# Theory for the relative scale of objects?

Tags: universe, perception

I've been pondering what Prof. Brian Cox said in an interview (still searching for it) where he said something along the lines of: *we (human beings) are very small relative to the earth, universe.* I'll update this once I find the interview.

However, this is startlingly obvious when I hold a single grain of sand in the palm of my hand, that *I* am actually very small.

This made me think about how similar we are, as a collective, to other forms of life, in terms of patterns of behaviour. A crude example, society consists of groups who work to ensure the safety of others, such as law enforcement. In biology, there are 'T cells' that form part of the immune system, and T cells have been described as constantly patrolling looking out for rouge cells.

Now, my point is this: it appears to me then humanity follows the same patterns of behaviour as other biological processes and indeed other forms of life, such as colonies of ants.

Brian Cox's explanation made me think about the Mandelbrot set, and I've formed the view that these different levels of existence (from smallest to largest) all follow the same patterns of behaviour and contain the same sorts of components.

What branch of Physics attempts to explain such an observation? That is, an explanation for why or how life and matter display the same fundamental characteristics and behaviour?

Albert Einstein, for example - as a human being, despite his relative size, was able to conceive of his theories, ultimately leading to the capability of harnessing the fundamental laws of nature. The atomic bomb is indeed massive from our perception, but relative to the forming of a new star, it is just a blip.

Ants may perceive human beings to be massive, and visa versa - but in truth, aside from visual perception, we are in fact not that much bigger, but still out intelligence grants us a much larger status.

I appreciate this question borders on basic biology and philosophy - but I just wanted to know if there is an aspect of Physics dealing with such things as relative size of objects, and how life and matter behaves.

Answer (score 0):

Self-perpetuating homeostatic systems require certain things. They must metabolize their environments, extracting resources from their surroundings, altering them, and rejecting waste. They must protect their resources from other self-perpetuating systems and the environment using passive barriers, threat identification heuristics, and active countermeasures. They must have mechanisms for storing information about how to build themselves, mechanisms for building new versions of themselves or parts thereof, and mechanisms for terminating the building process to keep it from consuming all their resources.

These mechanisms pop up for any self-perpetuating process because they're logically necessary for self-perpetuation. Similarities between them across wildly different types of process, however, are exaggerated. T-cells, for example, are *not* like miniature policemen patrolling in search of miniature criminals; they're like blind, balloon riding psychopaths that float around aimlessly and throw hand grenades at anything that smells weird. They do, however, fill a similar role to police, in that they are a mechanism for differentiating between properly functioning system elements and malfunctioning or foreign system elements and eliminating the latter's capacity to harm the system.

Regarding scale and physics: there's an interesting predictable three-way correlation between power output, mass, and life-span that holds (very roughly, with frequent outliers) all the way from chemical respiratory structures in organelles to cities. That is, a majority of the time, if you know how much power output something has and how much it weighs, you can guess what its life span will be; if you know something's life span and power output, you can guess how much it weighs; and if you know weight and life span, you can guess power output, within about an order of magnitude. The last I read any research about this was around 2012, at which time there were some ideas for why this might be the case, but no candidate for a theory.

Comment: The 3 parts of your reply helps, it reminded me that - even at relatively minute microscopic levels of being (human), the forces which govern us, and the forces we are able to harness and utilise are, as it were - of the same potential. E=MC2, for example. But Prof.BC also pointed out the sort of energy levels required by a relatively tiny life form to be able to travel the expanse of space, we would, he suggested, be more likely to use and be perceived as travelling in microscopic machines as opposed to giant ships, since the former would be more efficient.